# Extract more info from themoviedb using typeahead.js and put it in other inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead, html-input

I'm using typeahead.js to get movie info from themoviedb api. I need when the user type the movie's title get the year of the movie and the ID of the movie to be added automatically to other inputs.

So when the user using the input Movie title and he click on the suggested titles, It will  automatically add the year and the movie id to the other inputs

### HTML Code

```
<input class="typeahead" placeholder="Movie Title Here"><br>
<input class="year" placeholder="Year Here">
<input class="id" placeholder="Year ID">
```

### JS code

Look close to the return (at Line 12) there is the info I need to be transferred to other inputs

```
var movies = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    remote: {
        url: 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=470fd2ec8853e25d2f8d86f685d2270e&query=%QUERY&search_type=ngram',
        filter: function (movies) {
            // Map the remote source JSON array to a JavaScript array
            return $.map(movies.results, function (movie) {
                    return {
                        id: movie.id,
                        value: movie.original_title,
                        year: (movie.release_date.substr(0,4) ? movie.release_date.substr(0,4) : '')
                    };
                });
            }
        }
    });

// Initialize the Bloodhound suggestion engine
movies.initialize();

// Instantiate the Typeahead UI
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true
}, {
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: movies.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
    empty: [
        '<div class="empty-message">',
        'unable to find any Best Picture winners that match the current query',
        '</div>'
    ].join('\n'),
    suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p><strong>{{value}}</strong> – {{year}}</p>')
}

});
```

here is my code in action on jsfiddle to try yourself:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/ss8L24x8/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added a way to auto-populate the associated input controls here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/cmq80qx3/

The key part of the code to achieve the auto-population is:

```
bind("typeahead:selected", function (obj, datum, name) {
 $('.year').val(datum.year);
 $('.id').val(datum.id);
});
```

This code specifies the function which should be called when a typeahead value is selected, in this case it appropriately sets the values of the year and id inputs.

Comment: Thank you so much, Is there anyway if already there is a value like this http://jsfiddle.net/cmq80qx3/1/ when the user click on the input it will open suggestion list automatically (simulate down arrow key keypress) so he can click on the title and get the extra info to other inputs

Comment: No problem. You should create a separate question for what you ask for in your comment as it isn't really related to this question.

Comment: That is super helpful! I was struggling to find how to do this, and the docs don't give any examples like your bind one.